# HTTP mod proxying timing out

Tags: apache-2.2

Recently we have started to see very slow response times on our web server.   We are using apache on an outside web server and mod proxy passing into our web server internally.  Here is an excerpt from apache setup:

```
  KeepAlive On
  SetEnv proxy-initial-not-pooled 1
  ProxyPass /msp ourservernameurl/msp
```

The second proxy-initial-not-pooled setting we are recently trying due to a post on this board.

We also tried this from a post on this board here: [Proxy Error 502 "Reason: Error reading from remote server" with Apache 2.2.3 (Debian) mod_proxy and Jetty 6.1.18](https://serverfault.com/questions/185894/proxy-error-502-reason-error-reading-from-remote-server-with-apache-2-2-3-de):
      ProxyPass /msp ourservernameurl/msp retry=1 acquire=3000 timeout=600 Keepalive=on

However, this brought our proxying to the web server to a halt (non responsive) and may have contributed to having to do a restart on the internal server itself.

What we are seeing in the logs are multiple proxy timeouts:
[Mon Nov 18 20:35:33 2013] [error] [client ip] (70007)The timeout specified has expired: proxy: error reading status line from remote server ourservernameurl, referer: https://ourservername.com/secure/send-e-card
[Mon Nov 18 20:35:33 2013] [error] [client ip] proxy: Error reading from remote server returned by /EcardsDonate/loginVerificationAction.do, referer: https://ourservername.com/secure/send-e-card