# 502 from Apache over HTTPS with reverse proxy to Node server on different port

Tags: apache-2.4, proxy, reverse-proxy, node.js

I have a node application running on port 3030 for an API which I want to access over HTTPS.

If I visit http://api.example.com:3030/*** I can load a 200 response with no problem so the node application is definitely running, however if I visit https://api.example.com/**** I get the following error in the browser:

```
Proxy Error
The proxy server received an invalid response from an upstream server.
The proxy server could not handle the request GET /api/posts.
```

and the following in the apache error log:

```
[Sun Jun 03 15:30:47.942229 2018] [proxy_http:error] [pid 30884] (103)Software caused connection abort: [client xx.xx.xx.xx:xxxxx] AH01102: error reading status line from remote server api.example.com:3030
[Sun Jun 03 15:30:47.942414 2018] [proxy:error] [pid 30884] [client xx.xx.xx.xx:xxxxx] AH00898: Error reading from remote server returned by /***
```

This is my Apache config:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerName www.api.example.com
        ServerAlias api.example.com
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/xxxxxx/

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

<Directory /var/www/html/xxxxxx/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>
RewriteEngine on

SetEnv proxy-initial-not-pooled 1
SSLEngine On
SSLProxyEngine on
SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/cert.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem
Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/chain.pem
ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyPass / https://api.example.com:3030/
ProxyPassReverse / https://api.example.com:3030/

</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

Versions of Apache and Node:

- node 8.11.2
- Apache 2.4.7

Any support is greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Change the https in your proxy lines to http

Comment: did you try with KeepAlive On ? https://serverfault.com/questions/185894/proxy-error-502-reason-error-reading-from-remote-server-with-apache-2-2-3-de

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your nodejs expects HTTP on it's port, as is evident by your working test:

> If I visit http://api.example.com:3030/ I can load a 200 response with no problem

But you configured your Apache to access it via https

```
ProxyPass / https://api.example.com:3030/
ProxyPassReverse / https://api.example.com:3030/
```

Change your Apache configuration to use http and it will work.

```
ProxyPass / http://api.example.com:3030/
ProxyPassReverse / http://api.example.com:3030/
```

---

An additional note:
It is common practice not to make the ports of application servers public. You should configure nodejs to only listen on your loopback device (`127.0.0.1`) and then change your Proxy directives to connect to `localhost:3030` instead of `api.example.com`.