# Docker connectivity issue due to conflict with iptables-persitent

Tags: iptables, docker

I have run into a problem with my docker host.

### Setup:

Docker installation with multiple containers, serving websites.
Apache server on host is used as reverse proxy.

### Symptoms:

All websites show error 502 ProxyError

Answer (score 0):

### Cause:

Docker adds rules to the iptables chain. These rules can be different each time docker service is started.
If we use iptables-persistent to save rules in configuration file while docker service is running, all *temporary* docker rules are saved to the configuration and are not temporary anymore.
If we now reboot the server, the stored rules are loaded, and are different than the docker network configuration. (in my case ip address of the container has changed).

### Solution

I Removed all docker-created rules from the configuration files, and restarted the docker service.